# .each() method only applies to first element in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

I have a jQuery like so:

```
$('#corner .photo img').each(function() {
    var $img = $(this);
    var h = $img.height();
    var w = $img.width();
    $img.css('margin-top', +h / -2 + "px").css('margin-left',+ w/ -2 + "px");
});
```

It works in all browsers except in IE 7 and 8. In those browsers, it only applies the new property to the first element of #corner (which is the first .photo img).

If I remove #corner, it applies to all instances of ".photo img" inside it. However, I cannot remove the id #corner because some other parts of the HTML are using ".photo img" and I don't want this jQuery script to be applied to all. I only want it to be applied inside #corner.

Is there a way to solve this?

**EDIT:**

My bad, apparently there are multiple divs with the same name in the document, which are causing the problems in IE. I changed them to classes and it now works.

Comment: Can you include your HTML. It's possible that is the problem.

Comment: Maybe your HTML is incorrect and IE corrects it differently than other browsers, with the result that there is only one image inside `#corner`. It is hard to tell what is wrong given this code. jQuery definitely works in IE too. Maybe you can create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Try `alert($('#corner .photo img').length)` and tell us what is the output in IE?

Comment: I suspect the jQuery is just fine and the CSS isn't parsed correctly.. add `alert($img);` or something similar in the loop and see how many times you get the alert box.

Comment: You are all correct. The HTML has a problem. Fixed it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$('#corner').find('.photo img').each(...
```

By the way, IE does not like multiple items with the same ID. If you are using it this way with multiple `id="corner"` items them change that to a class and you should be fine.

Comment: What is the difference? Can you explain a bit?

Comment: Just updated with another thought. In terms of what you would GET from these methods, no difference, but you never know what quirks lie inside each browser so its worth trying it multiple ways if something that should work does not.